# How to create single sign on with many different system and different identification sources?

Tags: java, php, single-sign-on

For example i have three different systems.

1. system #1 is java web application with its own identification
2. system #2 is php application with its own identification
3. system #3 is .net web application with its own identification

can some give guide how to implement single sign on for this type of problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you achieved your goal? We have a similar problem at hand. Would appreciate if you could give your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [JSAIG-CAS](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Technical+Overview) ? You need to install CAS server and then all your different applications use the CAS clients which are available for various platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [OpenID](http://openid.net/)? They've done all of the work for you :)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick reply, but im looking a solution that i can install on my own server.